# Create one column out of several columns Rstudio or Excel

Tags: r, excel, col

I've tried to find an already existing question on this matter but I couldn't so that is why I'm asking here you:

### Summary:

I want to make ONE column out of several Columns. All the values in the columns are put in the same order as they are and also, the columns should be stacked below each other.

### Description and details

Below is an example of how my csv.file look like. However, note that there is >400 columns and that's why I don't want to do it manually in for example Excel. ALL columns has 24 rows each.

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6 ... X470
0   1   5   10  8   0      7
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
2   3   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
0   0   0   0   0   0      0
```

I want to "stack" all the columns in one column, as I've shortly described in the summary:

Info: The sign "..." below implies the rest of the values from that column.

```
VALUE  FROM COLUMN
0      X1   
0      X1   
2      X1   
...     
1      X2       
0      X2   
3      X2
...     
5      X3   
...     
10     X4
...  
8      X5
... 
0      X6
... 
7      X470
...
```

So in the end, instead of having 486 column where each of them have 24 rows. I will have 1 column with 11664 rows. It would be good if the origin column is written in a new column on the side (as showed above) but this is not "obligated".

OBS! Note that I've with this df just showed in general what I want to achieve, so clear and understandable commands are appreciated as I will apply it to my df.

**It doesn't matter if the solution is done in R or Excel! As long as it is easy to do**

---

I hope my description is clear, otherwise please let me know so I can try to describe again.

Many thanks for suggestions and help.

Kind regards, Elin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is pretty simple but requires loading the `reshape2` package which I think is included in base. As suggested above, `stack()` gives similar output, but reverses the columns.

```
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame("A" = 1:21, "B" = 21:41, "C" = 40:60)

> df
    A  B  C
1   1 21 40
2   2 22 41
3   3 23 42
4   4 24 43
5   5 25 44
6   6 26 45
7   7 27 46
8   8 28 47
9   9 29 48
10 10 30 49
11 11 31 50
12 12 32 51
13 13 33 52
14 14 34 53
15 15 35 54
16 16 36 55
17 17 37 56
18 18 38 57
19 19 39 58
20 20 40 59
21 21 41 60

melt(df)

> melt(df)
No id variables; using all as measure variables
  variable value
1         A     1
2         A     2
3         A     3
4         A     4
5         A     5
6         A     6
7         A     7
8         A     8
9         A     9
10        A    10
11        A    11
12        A    12
13        A    13
14        A    14
15        A    15
16        A    16
17        A    17
18        A    18
19        A    19
20        A    20
21        A    21
22        B    21
23        B    22
24        B    23
25        B    24
26        B    25
27        B    26
28        B    27
29        B    28
30        B    29
31        B    30
32        B    31
33        B    32
34        B    33
35        B    34
36        B    35
37        B    36
38        B    37
39        B    38
40        B    39
41        B    40
42        B    41
43        C    40
44        C    41
45        C    42
46        C    43
47        C    44
48        C    45
49        C    46
50        C    47
51        C    48
52        C    49
53        C    50
54        C    51
55        C    52
56        C    53
57        C    54
58        C    55
59        C    56
60        C    57
61        C    58
62        C    59
63        C    60
```

Comment: This was also awesome! How easy everything is when knowing how to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `stack` to get the values in one column and the colnames in the next.

```
stack(df)
```

---

Or use `unlist`

```
data.frame(VALUE=unlist(df),
          fromColumn= rep(names(df), each=nrow(df)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VBA user defined function to do the job:

```
Function ConcatCols(Colrange As Variant) As Variant
Dim LongCol() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim NumCols As Long, NumRows As Long, NumRows2 As Long

If TypeName(Colrange) = "Range" Then Colrange = Colrange.Value2

NumRows = UBound(Colrange)
NumCols = UBound(Colrange, 2)
NumRows2 = NumRows * NumCols
ReDim LongCol(1 To NumRows2, 1 To 1)

k = 1
For i = 1 To NumCols
    For j = 1 To NumRows
        LongCol(k, 1) = Colrange(j, i)
        k = k + 1
    Next j
Next i
ConcatCols = LongCol
End Function
```

Enter the code in a VBA module then enter =ConcatCols(A1:RL24) as an array function (Ctrl-Shift-Enter) in column RM (or wherever you want) to view the entire concatenated column, or call from a VBA sub to write the data to the spreadsheet.